# Meteor reusable components

Tags: meteor

Meteor's reusable UI components is still far away on the roadmap. What's the best community approved way to create reusable components? A system based on Session seems so global.

Let's say I want to create 2 different chat channels on 1 page at the time. What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you're doing chat through collections...

I would make it such that a certain value is added to the chat JSON going into the MongoDB. Say for instance, user `test` sends a message `hello world` in chat box `1`. The JSON I'd send would look something like

`{name: 'test', message: 'hello world', num: 1}`

Then, in my chat helper thing, wherever I'm displaying new chats, I'd use a get method like this

`UI.registerHelper(getChat, function(n){return Messages.find({num: n});})`

Which would be called in the HTML with

`{{#each getChat 1}}` or `{{#each getChat 2}}` or whatever, depending on how many chat boxes you have.

This would basically only return values that correspond to the specific chat box.

Good luck.

Comment: This stuff is new in blaze?

Comment: Not really, no. The only real 'new' thing is the syntax. It used to be  `Handlebars.registerHelper` but, with 0.8.0, it's `UI.registerHelper`.

Comment: How do I get the 1 and 2 to be a variable? Like if I want to insert the chatroom ID

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by make it a variable. As in, dynamic?

Comment: Yes exactly, programmable ids?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use something dynamic instead of fixed param value, you can try this

```
// In memory collection for demonstration purpose
Messages = new Meteor.Collection(null);

if (Messages.find().count() === 0) {
    Messages.insert({name: 'test2', num: 1});
    Messages.insert({name: 'test5', num: 2});
    // [...] Init some test data
}

Template.test.helpers({
    // you can also use a collection
    chats: function() { return [{num:1}, {num:2}] },
});

// Took from Bob's example
UI.registerHelper('getChat', function(n){
    return Messages.find({num: n});
});
```

And your template

```
<template name="test">
    {{#each chats}}
        {{! num refer to a property of 'this'}}
        {{#each getChat num}}
            {{name}} <BR />
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

You can read more about Custom Block Helpers in Blaze [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#new-pattern-for-defining-custom-block-helpers)